# Apply a function to two IDs

Tags: javascript

I have the following function:

```
<script>  function setFries(){
var el = document.getElementById("burger");
if(el.checked)
  document.getElementById("opt1").disabled = false;
else
 document.getElementById("opt1").disabled = true; }  </script>
```

This makes a select box become ungreyed if a radio is selected.

I have another select box that I would like to become ungreyed two, with an ID of "opt2"

How would I add this to the above function.

I have tried:

```
  document.getElementById("opt1").disabled && document.getElementById("opt2").disabled
```

and a few variations on this, but haven't been able to get it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like that?

```
function setFries() {
    var el = document.getElementById("burger");
    if (el.checked) {
        document.getElementById("opt1").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("opt2").disabled = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("opt1").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("opt2").disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Too many lines... `false` and `true` are oppositely related to `el.checked`. No need to to an `if` branching... Have a look at my answer.

Comment: @OferZelig Depends on coding style.

Comment: hmmm... agree that sometimes clarity is better, but - 8 lines instead of 2? And even in your suggested verbose form it could have been clearer. In addition, you now have about 4 lines to maintain had your business rule changed, which is error-prone.

Answer (score 3):

```
<script>
function setFries(){
    var el = document.getElementById("burger");
    document.getElementById("opt1").disabled = document.getElementById("opt2").disabled = !e1.checked;
</script>
```

Clean & elegant.

Answer (score 1):

```
function setFries(){
  var el = document.getElementById("burger");
  document.getElementById("opt1").disabled =document.getElementById("opt2").disabled= !el.checked;
}
```

However, a better approach would be to assign the same CSS class to both and change based on class.
Eg :

```
function setFries(){
   var el = document.getElementById("burger");    
   document.getElementsByClassName('yourCommonClassName').disabled = !el.checked;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently your actions on the if and else branches are single statements. You need to turn them into blocks so more actions can be executed when the condition is true or false:

```
if (...) { // notice the brackets
  // action 1
  // action 2
} else {
  // action 3
  // action 4
}
```

`a && b` is a logical operation. You don't need that. To execute two actions, you simply write them one after the other:

```
document.getElementById("opt1").disabled = false;
document.getElementById("opt2").disabled = false;
```

Finally, you can extract the elements to change in variables just as you did with the burger one, so the code is easier to read.

Full example:

```
<script>  
function setFries(){
  var el = document.getElementById("burger");
  var opt1 = document.getElementById("opt1");
  var opt2 = document.getElementById("opt2");
  if(el.checked) {
    opt1.disabled = false;
    opt2.disabled = false;
  } else {
    opt1.disabled = true;
    opt2.disabled = true;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Wouldn't be better to have a 2-liner?

Comment: It depends if that is the only thing the OP wants to do in the function. A two liner is harder to change. Anyway, i already upvoted your solution because i like terseness over readability as well. Bonus potato if you give up on the el variable and turn it into a one-liner ;). EDIT: I like terseness, but i don't use it with someone who is obviously just learning.

Comment: Not a problem :)

`document.getElementById("opt1").disabled = document.getElementById("opt2").disabled = !document.getElementById("burger").checked;`